# After-life transmission of spiritual power (Shakthi)

Tags: puranas, mantras

To avenge Kauravas who imprisoned his father, Shakuni used his father's after- life power to continue to transmit his will. He urged Shakuni to play a game of dice in a deceitful way with his bone dice rolling and transmitting energy favorably in order to defeat Pandavas through such evil spiritual betting trick.

In the nearer past also Sai Baba of Shirdi has undertaken to benefit willing devotees through a similar medium but with an entirely holy intent. Men of intense spiritual energy through the ages had and do have a capabity to transmit it by their intent alone without any bone or such medium to the deserving and suffering... sometimes in reply to their prayers or thapas. One also hears about "Shakthi paathams"..

It is known/ believed that certain esoteric Mantras have power to instill peace to restless departed souls by certain invocations and others are also used in religious functions to purify and and bring in peace..

Are there Puranic references to exert influence by transmission(Tantric or otherwise) after a person's death or also when living by design/intention for whatever purpose?

( It is well known that Shakthi transfer is made to occur between spirited persons e.g., from Sri Ramakrishna to Vivekananda on two occasions.. however all this during their *living* periods.)

Comment: But how did you come to this conclusion that powers were transmitted from A to B? For instance "Shakuni used his father's after- life power to continue to transmit his will"

Comment: thats what I heard in my childhood as a story about Gandhar king Shakuni in Mahabharatha. Wiki source refers to something similar.. his brothers turned into arrows to pierce Bhishma.

Comment: So it means similar phenomenon happened with Ashwathama as well when his father Drona was killed in the battle?

Comment: I do not know... Ashwathama is supposed to be deathless.

Comment: I know he is immortal but the transmission process would be applicable to him as well .. no?

Comment: That story of Shakuni taking revenge has absolutely no basis in Hindu scripture.

Comment: But some parts of  ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakuni) in Mahabharata say so.

Comment: Sakuni's story does not find a place in Vyasa's Mahabharatha.
This is more of a local folklore based on abridged version of Mahabaratha written later. Even the story of KArna donating the merit acquired from his donations to LLord Krishna is not part of the original Mahabaratha written by Vyasa.

Comment: In Apprenticed to a Himalayan Master, Sri M says that his guru Maheshwarnath Babaji transferred spiritual powers to him when he was about to leave body. Usually, gurus transfer their powers to their chief disciple for the welfare of the world. If my memory serves me well then the same thing happened in case of Sri Ramakrishna and Swami Vivekananda.

Comment: @ShankarMurthy However it appears the folklore is strong throughout India.

Comment: @ Chinmay Sarupria There are some godmen even nowadays undertaking "Shakthipaath" on devotees. I am intrigued how by intention alone such forward and backward transfers can be effected by Yogis. In Mahabharatha Lord Krishna temporarily imparted a visual Shakthi to Dritharashtra in order to see Him and then shortly afterwards withdrew it.

Comment: @ Keshav Srinivasan  Question is not about what Shakuni did but whether such powers at all existed at that time.